# How can i call an element in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

i need to call a cakePHP element in an Ajax function; when the user clicks an item  want to populate a DIV with the content of an element.
The problem is that i don't know how to properly create that element because i call the url but cakephp renders all the webpage instead of only the element.
How can i call only the element through a controller action?

Thanks in advance
c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling an action, but within it, specify:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

That makes it so it does not use a layout file.

Then, within the view of that action, just echo the element - nothing else:

```
<?php
echo $this->element('myElement');
?>
```

Comment: great, my friend, you saved my day!

Comment: There are two answers below that seem better than mine just specifying which element to render.

Answer (score 3):

faster way: `$this->render('/elements/myElement','ajax');` at the end of your controller action.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->layout = NULL;
$this->autoRender = false;


// your code



$this->render('/elements/myElement');
```

Comment: I suppose this is a better answer because you can call element within controller action.